# NSFetchedResultsController with custom cells

Tags: uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm using a NSFetchedResultsController and I have no idea how to fix my current problem.
My headers in my table view are cells rather than real headers, because I don't want the headers to stick at the top while scrolling.

The message is pretty clear about it:

```
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)
```

But the number of rows in the section after the insertion of 1 row needs to be 2! How can I let the table view know about this? I'm already doing stuff like this:

```
indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row + 1
                               inSection:section];

newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newIndexPath.row + 1
                                  inSection:section];
```

But in this particular case it doesn't work, after the first crash everything works like it should, because that's the only time two cells are inserted while only one from core data itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found the solution to my problem!

I just check if it's the first time when a cell from the NSFetchedResultsController is being added through the NSFetchedResultsController delegate (didChangeObject:), if it is, I manually add another row.

Snippet:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
   didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    NSInteger section = 1;
    indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row + 1
                                   inSection:section];

    NSMutableArray *newIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [controller.sections objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([sectionInfo numberOfObjects] == 1) {
        newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newIndexPath.row
                                          inSection:section];
        [newIndexPaths addObject:newIndexPath];
    }

    newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newIndexPath.row + 1
                                      inSection:section];
    [newIndexPaths addObject:newIndexPath];

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:newIndexPaths
                                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```